# iOS: NavigationController: BarBackButtonItem influence width

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I influence the width of a BarBackButtonItem. The title of my former UIViewController is very long and I expected iOS to shorten it a bit with '...' truncation in the middle but this is not the case. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to manually truncate the text that appears in the `backBarButtonItem`.

To do this, implement code as follows in (say) the init method of the calling view controller:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"<truncated title>" 
                                      style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                     target: nil 
                                     action: nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

On your method which *pushes* the view, have it change its own title to "Back".  Then, in that same controller's `viewWillAppear:` code, have it set its title to what it should be.  This method works well and doesn't cause any jarring animation problems, and lets you go back and forth.

(If you don't want back, and you simply want your title truncated, just truncate the title here manually)